# Possible to use more than one push provider in android?

Tags: android, push-notification, manifest

So i'm wondering if there is way to use more than one push provider in android?

Im trying to implement both One Signal (which automagically adds correct info to manifest file) and MoEngage (which you have to manually add correct info to manifest file).

Answer (score 0):

(Note: I help work on OneSignal)

Yes.The OneSignal Android SDK is designed to work well even when there are other push SDKs in the app.

A small number of other push SDKs may not be designed to work correctly in cases where there is another Push SDK in the app, but we we haven't had any reports of issues with using MoEngage and OneSignal together.